# Update Python Gauge

Tags: python, gauge

```
import tkinter as tk
import tk_tools

root = tk.Tk()

p = tk_tools.RotaryScale(root, max_value=100.0, unit='psi')
p.grid()

p.set_value(32.7)

root.mainloop()
```

How I can update this gauge?

I would like the gauge to be Updated

Comment: Have a look at this example from the library you are using: https://github.com/slightlynybbled/tk_tools/blob/master/examples/gauge.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after` method to schedule an update ([tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method)).

If you look at the official examples on GitHub you'll find one for the gauge specifically (https://github.com/slightlynybbled/tk_tools/blob/master/examples/gauge.py). The relevant snippet for updating the gauge looks like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tk_tools

root = tk.Tk()

p = tk_tools.RotaryScale(root, max_value=100.0, unit='psi')
p.grid()

count = 30.0
p.set_value(count)

def update_gauge():
    global p, count
    count += 1.0
    p.set_value(count)
    root.after(50, update_gauge)

root.after(50, update_gauge)
root.mainloop()
```

This would update the gauge every 50ms and increase its value by 1 each time.